# Connect two ESP8266 using serial link

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to build a gateway for ESP-NOW (https://github.com/HarringayMakerSpace/ESP-Now) and I would like to get help with connecting two esp8266 (nodemcu + esp01) with serial link (for use as gateway).

[image]

What I done so far:

```
ESP01 ... NODEMCU
-----------------
3V3   ...  3v3
GND   ...  GND
CH_PD ...  3v3
TX    ...  RX
RX    ...  TX
```

The problem is that with this setup NodeMCU (and I think ESP01 too) is not booting (probably because TX is connected?). What's the correct way to connect two ESP8266 as described in ESP-NOW project?

NodeMCU is running this code:

https://github.com/HarringayMakerSpace/ESP-Now/tree/master/EspNowFromSerialGateway

ESP-01 is running this code:

https://github.com/HarringayMakerSpace/ESP-Now/tree/master/EspNowToSerial

Comment: RX to TX. receive to transmit. and pull-up for io 0 of the esp-01

Comment: Ahoj Juraj, I tried this as well, but the main problem is not this. If I remove ESP-01, it boots correctly.

Comment: the code running on nodemcu seems to use softwareserial (on pins 14 and 12 - which are Dx and Dy on the NodeMCU - where x and y are seemingly arbitrary numbers), but you're connecting the hardware serial - I could be misreading the code though - I mean, how do you know it's not booting anyway?

Comment: This was the problem, problem solved. Thank you. If you post this as answer I can accept as solution.